# stack of a c program

Tags: c

how the stack would look like for the following program if I give input as 5.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fibonacci(int number)
{
  int retval;
  if (0 == number){
    return 0;
  }
  if (1 == number){
    return 1;
  }
  return(fibonacci(number-1) + fibonacci(number-2));
}

int main()
{
  int number = 0;
  int fibvalue = 1;
  while (1){
    printf("please enter the number\n");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    fibvalue = fibonacci(number);
    printf("computed fibonacci value %d\n", fibvalue);
  }
  return 1;
}
```

also give me links where i can learn about it

Comment: Shame on you for returning 1 from `main`.

Comment: If this is homework, please tag as such.

Comment: And is this a homework problem?  Tag it appropriately if it is, and let us know some more specific questions you have.

Comment: At what point during execution do you want to know what the stack 'looks like', for example.

Comment: +1 Mark, what should you return?

Comment: @Mark:  Technically he doesn't; that `return 1` is unreachable.  :-)

Comment: @VoodooChild nothing, the return is unreachable, so returning an error code is pointless.

Comment: Have I forgotten that much C?  Or has the code changed?  That return at the end of main() does not look unreachable to me.  And since main() was declared as int instead of void, OP should return something.  I'd argue that declaring it int was the problem; not the return.

Answer (score 1):

Use a debugger, for example, [GDB](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/).

Shameless plug - take a look at [my GDB intro presentation](http://www.fetissov.org/public/gdb/) at [New York City BSD User Group](http://www.nycbug.org) - there are plenty of examples of Fibonacci stack traces there.